# Array json parsing

Tags: php, arrays, json, parsing, jsonparser

i'm parsing a json file (api rest) but i can't solve a problem. This is the json file.

```
Array
(
    [110197275197292] => Array
        (
            [mid] => 110197275197292
            [home] => FC Den Bosch
            [away] => SC Telstar
            [country_leagues] => Netherlands - Eerste Divisie
            [leagues] => Eerste Divisie
            [country] => Netherlands
            [score] => 
            [home_score] => 0
            [away_score] => 0
            [periodID] => 
            [periodTXT] => 
            [periodTime] => 1632923759
            [startTime] => 1633111200
            [lastUpdateTime] => 1632923357
            [minutes] => 0
            [status] => 1
            [importancy] => 281
            [odds] => Array
                (
                    [home] => 2.45
                    [draw] => 3.70
                    [away] => 2.40
                    [1st-1] => 2.90
                    [1st-0] => 2.35
                    [1st-2] => 2.87
                    [2nd-1] => 2.70
                    [2nd-0] => 2.70
                    [2nd-2] => 2.65
```

with this code below i print the value of the array, and work.

```
foreach ($response as $key1 => $value1){
    echo $response[$key1]['home'] .'<br>';
}
```

Now i would insert the value of the array in a variable, something like that

```
foreach ($response as $key1 => $value1){
    $prova = $response[$key1]['home'];
}

<?php echo $prova; ?>
```

This way I could recall it in an html table. This code print me only one value of the array and does not loop (foreach). The value that prints in this case is Nashville SC which is a value found in the json file. Where is my mistake? there is a way to encapsulate array values in a variable and then recall it later in the html code?

Comment: You've stepped out of the foreach and are only printing the last value. You should probably move the echo inside the foreach.

Comment: _Of course_ you only get the last value _after_ the loop, because you are _overwriting_ the value of this variable in each loop iteration.

Comment: It does loop just fine. But you're ***overwriting*** `$prova` in every iteration, so only the last value remains. Did you mean to create an *array* of values…?

Answer (score 1):

You are always overwriting the `$prova` variable with the home team. You should either convert `$prova` to an array and work with it or move the `echo` inside your loop to print everything.

Moreover you should use more distinct names to your variables so both we and you understand your code.

```
//1. echo way
foreach ($response as $matchDate => $matchData){
    $prova = $matchData['home'];
    echo $prova;
}


//2. array way
$prova = [];
foreach ($response as $matchDate => $matchData){
    $prova[$matchDate] = $matchData['home'];
}
var_dump($prova); //This will print the whole array of home teams.
```